# How do I parse JSON in golang?

Tags: json, go

I tried to "Unmarshal" json in golang, but it doesn't seem to be working.
I get 0 printed out instead of 1. What am I doing wrong?

```
package main

import (
  "fmt"
  "encoding/json"
)

type MyTypeA struct {
  a int
}

func main() {
  var smthng MyTypeA
  jsonByteArray := []byte(`{"a": 1}`)
  json.Unmarshal(jsonByteArray, &smthng)
  fmt.Println(smthng.a)
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two problems with your code.

1. You need to export fields or Marshal won't work, read about it [here](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Exported_identifiers).
2. Your package must be called main or `func main` won't be executed.

http://play.golang.org/p/lJixko1QML

```
type MyTypeA struct {
    A int
}

func main() {
    var smthng MyTypeA
    jsonByteArray := []byte(`{"a": 1}`)
    json.Unmarshal(jsonByteArray, &smthng)
    fmt.Println(smthng.A)
}
```

Comment: oops, the foo was a copy paste error. I fixed it so that doesn't throw people off in the future. Thanks for the answer!!!